# What is printed when you call an object in R?

Tags: r

When you call an object, as in

```
x = 6
x
```

is there a method that is called to decide what is going to be printed in the console? Take `lm` objects as an example, when you call a `lm`, just some elements of the list (the object structure is a list) in a special formatting.

```
lm(cars$dist~cars$speed)

#Call:
#lm(formula = cars$dist ~ cars$speed)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)   cars$speed  
#    -17.579        3.932
```

How can I modify how objects of a certain class are printed when the object is called, for example, if I wanted a result like

```
lm(cars$dist~cars$speed)
#cars$dist = -17.579 + 3.932*cars$speed
```

**Edit:** So based on the comments and some testing, I was thinking calling `x` and `print(x)` would have the same output. But I tried modifying the `print` method for the `lm` class.

```
setMethod("print", signature = "lm", function(x) print(x$coef))
```

which resulted in a different printing format, working as expected

```
print(lm(cars$dist~cars$speed))
#(Intercept)  cars$speed 
# -17.579095    3.932409
```

But on the other hand, when I call

```
lm(cars$dist~cars$speed)
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = cars$dist ~ cars$speed)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)   cars$speed  
#    -17.579        3.932
```

Shouldn't `print(object)` have the same result as `object`?

Comment: There are many different methods for printing stuff. See `methods("print")`. You can define your own class and print method for that class

Comment: It is one of the functions you see from `methods(print)` depending on the class of the object given to `print()`.

Comment: To add to what others have said, if you have an object of class, say, `Freguglia` and there is a method (a function) `print.Freguglia` it will be used, if that function doesn't exist, `print.default` will be used.

Comment: I edited the question, I think it's clearer now. My goal isn't to change the print method, but what is printed when I call the object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `lm` nor `print` are part of the S4 system, so "SetMethod" is the wrong syntax. If instead you use the S3 syntax:

`print.lm <- function(x) print(x$coef)`

It does as you say (e.g. `fit <- lm(cars$dist ~ cars$speed)` yields the same results when calling `print(fit)` and just `fit`).